# How to detect ADB device connected to my PC

Tags: c#, android, usb, adb, driver

I am trying to find a way to automatically detect a connected ADB device to my PC. One of solutions I found stupid is to make a timer and parse the output of `adb devices` comand.

How can I use events or something at least to recognize that an android device(s) (with USB debugging turned on) connected and disconnected? Then I can use ADB devices to show the list of connected devices. Or should I use another approach?

Answer (score 0):

You can use RegisterDeviceNotification with GUID_DEVINTERFACE_USB_DEVICE. You will receive WM_DEVICECHANGE with wParam set to DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL every time a new USB device appears, you device should show up under "adb devices" shortly after.